# Rails create a model from form that isn't stored in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

I have an account model that i want to create from the registration controller and form.

index.html.erb

```
<div id="registration">
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
<% if @account.errors.any? %>
```

register_controller.rb

```
class RegisterController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @account = Account.new
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(parames[:account])
  end
end
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'register/index'
  get 'register/create'
```

My current issue is undefined method `accounts_path' for #<#:0x007fd9f2fd8468> from the form_for() method

Am I mixing things up because of the names of the classes?

Comment: by default, `form_for` will try to "guess" the URL to submit the form to. In your case, you don't want the form to submit to `accounts_path` but to `form_for @account, url: registers_path` (if you defined in your routes.rb `resources :register`, if not I will need to see your routes configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form_for(@account)` will auto-set some of the attributes of the form, such as "action", which is where the form submits to.  If you want to change this to something else then use the url option.  You can pass this a path helper or just put the url in.  eg

```
<!-- if you have a named path you can use the helper for it -->
<%= form_for @article, url: create_register_path %>
```

or

```
<!-- alternatively just pass the url -->
<%= form_for @article, url: "/register/create" %>
```

or

```
<!-- or you can pass the url as a hash if you prefer -->  
<%= form_for @article, url: {controller: "register", action: "create"} %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

EDIT:  I just noticed in your edit to your post that "register/create" is set as a `get` route.  This means you will need to tell your form to use the `get` method as well: it defaults to `post`.

```
<%= form_for @article, url: "/register/create", :method => :get %>
```

Comment: BTW, it is generally good practise to have your urls/controllers match your object class names - it will save you some confusion, and you'll have to do less overriding of defaults.